# Dropbox SDK for iOS works on simulator, not on actual device

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a project involving an iOS app communicating with another device by way of syncing data through Dropbox.

It works perfectly fine when I run the software on the iPhone Simulator (it syncs, uploads, downloads without issues), but when I load it onto my actual device, I get load/save errors.

The app on both the simulator and iPhone was successfully linked to my Dropbox account.

Some errors when I try do load requests:

```
2015-05-18 23:27:19.385 [2218:923269] [ERROR] DBRequest#connectionDidFinishLoading: error moving temp file to desired location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)

2015-05-18 23:27:19.387 [2218:923269] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/dropbox/Projekt 2 (1)/Program/Units.txt - (516) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x174077700 {path=/Projekt 2 (1)/Program/Units.txt, destinationPath=/...}
```

Samples of the dropbox related code in my app:

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let session = DBSession(appKey: "myAppKey", appSecret: "myAppSecret", root: kDBRootDropbox)
    DBSession.setSharedSession(session)
    ...
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if DBSession.sharedSession().handleOpenURL(url) {
        if DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
            // Linking was successfull.
        }
        return true
    }
    return false 
}
```

In ViewControllerCausingErrors.swift:

```
class ViewControllerCausingErrors: DBRestClientDelegate {

    var dbClient = DBRestClient()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dbClient = DBRestClient(session: DBSession.sharedSession())
        self.dbClient.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
        if !DBSession.sharedSession().isLinked() {
            DBSession.sharedSession().linkFromController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Chunk of code i use to download a file, elsewhere in the VC

```
if let localPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Units", ofType: "txt") {
    // Download file from Dropbox to local path.
    let dropboxPath = Constants.Dropbox.Download.UnitFilePath
    self.dbClient.loadFile(dropboxPath, intoPath: localPath)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203816815-Dropbox-SDK-for-iOS-works-on-simulator-not-on-actual-device ]

Comment: Have you found a solution? Could you provide a code?

Comment: @Fengson Yes I did. If you want to know what caused the problem and how I solved it, check out my post on the Dropbox forums: [Link](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203816815-Dropbox-SDK-for-iOS-works-on-simulator-not-on-actual-device)

Comment: Already did but this didn't help me, getting the same error. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSError_Codes), error code 516 is:

```
NSFileWriteFileExistsError = 516,
```

It sounds like there's a file at the supplied `localPath` on the device (called `destinationPath` in the error), but not on the simulator, causing `loadFile` to not be able to write the file from the download.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in the NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Units", ofType: "txt"). NSBundle is used in simulator but not in actual device. You just place Units.txt in your loadFile function

self.dbClient.loadFile(dropboxPath, intoPath: "Units.txt")